# Graphene Enums not working when using without creating a new class

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

From the [documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/enums/#enums), it's evident that we are not bound to create new classes for using Enums.

I have the following code snippet:

```
from graphene import Enum, InputObjectType

GRAPH_TYPES = [
    ('step', 'Step graph'),
    ('bar', 'Bar graph'),
    ('line', 'Line graph'),
    ('dot', 'Dot graph'),
]


class DataType(Enum):
    VELOCITY = 'velocity'
    ACCELERATION = 'accelration'


class SomeInput(InputObjectType):
    data_type = DataType('DataTypeEnum')
    graph_type = Enum('GraphTypeEnum', GRAPH_TYPES)
```

When I head over to [GraphiQL](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), I am able to see `SomeInput` but `graph_type` is missing inside.

**Package versions:**

- graphene-django==2.12.1
- graphene==2.1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, it turns out to be something related to the initialization of the declared Enum.

The inline declaration `Enum('GraphTypeEnum', GRAPH_TYPES)` has to be updated like this:

`Enum('GraphTypeEnum', GRAPH_TYPES)()`.